# Remember preference (Active/Newest/Unanswered (my tags)

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When going to the main view, the app doesn't remember my viewing preference from before. Its always two extra taps (unlike the website that highlights the questions I am actually interested in.

Also as an aside - the view shows no indication of working in the background as it's being changed. Sometimes I didn't even see that it had loaded the questions I wanted, it took me 3-4 tries before it dawned on me.